# Click on tab to scroll to top of answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Please add a button to scroll to the top of answers tab, for questions with many/long answers.

Or, we could have the answers tab, when clicked, scrolls to the top of the list. **<-** (This is expected behaviour of lists with titles). This could similarly be done for the question tab as well. Example:

[image]

Comment: Good idea, we'll add this. Also, what is up with that font?

Comment: changed my system default font to "choco cooky" - the others are too boring or too whacky. If you're interested (forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1610701).

Answer (score 2):

This will be in the next version: v0.1.15

Comment: The font too, I hope.

Comment: If you cross your eyes while looking at our app it will probably work.